# TinyMCE bug IE call tinyMCE.editors

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce

I have TinyMCE version 3.5.8. I want to call tinyMCE object and it tinyMCE.editors. In Firefox and Chrome no problem. In IE 11 is a problem.

```
if (typeof(tinyMCE) != "undefined") {
  var n = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < tinyMCE.editors.length; i++) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Firefox and Chrome passes for cycle without problems but the problem is in IE
tinyMCE.editors.length return 0.

When a console dump `TinyMCE` I see "editors" correctly, but when you call `tinyMCE.editors` it returns an empty array.

I also tried tinyMCE['editors'] - the same problem in IE.

Please help. Thanks

---

any ideas?

Still, I would detailed description of the problem. 
I updated the TinyMCE - version 4
use jQuery - v1.11.3

I tried the code cleanly without other javascript codes followes:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../js/jquery.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../tinymce4/tinymce.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../tinymce4/_tinymce.advanced.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea class="wysiwyg" id="a1" name="a1">

    </textarea>
    <textarea class="wysiwyg" id="a2" name="a2">

    </textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">      
        jQuery(window).bind('load', function () {
            var editors = getTinyMCEEditors();
        });
        /**
         * Get TinyMCE Editors on page
         * @returns Object Editors Id
         */
        function getTinyMCEEditors(filterClass) {
            var ed = {};
            if (typeof(tinyMCE) != "undefined") {

   // THIS IS ERROR - return null array 
                console.log(tinyMCE.editors);

                var n = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < tinyMCE.editors.length; i++) {
                    if ($('#' + tinyMCE.editors[i].id).hasClass(filterClass)) {
                        ed[n] = tinyMCE.editors[i].id;
                        n++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return ed;
        }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

console.log(tinyMCE.editors); RETURN EMPTY ARRAY

Answer (score 0):

Where is your init call to actually get TinyMCE to take over those textareas? Perhaps this is simply a timing issue?  `tinymce.editors` won't contain anything until the initialization process is complete.

EDIT: I would try triggering your `getTinyMCEEditors()` call in the `init()` itself - TinyMCE gives you the ability to do this

TinyMCE 4 Code:

```
tinymce.init({
    ....
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function () {
          //run your code here
        });
    }
    ....
}
```

TinyMCE 3 Code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
            //run your code here
        });
    }
});
```

As JavaScript is asynchronous running your code on Window load is no guarantee that TinyMCE is done initializing the editors.   Moving the code to the init's setup and triggering it on editor 'init' would ensure that the editors are in place before the code is run.

Comment: tinymce.editors is called like this:

`jQuery(window).bind('load', function () {var editors = TinyMCEEditors(); });`

Comment: Where is the code for the `TinyMCEEditors()` function?  Its not in the example code above.  All I see in your code is a function that wants to work with `tinymce.editors` ... what I don't see in your code is any type of call to `tinymce.init()` which would be needed to actually invoke the editor inside a textarea. Where and how are you initializing TinyMCE for the `a1` and `a2` textareas?

Comment: Hello, function `tinymce.init()` is called in the file `https://.../tinymce4/_tinymce.advanced.js`
`tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.wysiwyg",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality textcolor paste textcolor colorpicker"
    ], ...
});`

Comment: See my edit above ... As JavaScript is asynchronous, running your code on Window load is no guarantee that TinyMCE is done initializing the editors. Moving the code to the init's setup and triggering it on editor 'init' would ensure that the editors are in place before the code is run.